# Override Webpage CTRL + zoom action

Tags: html, zooming

How to Override Webpage CTRL + zoom action.

Like in Figma CTRL+ zooms into canvas instead of whole page.
Also I want to utilize Mac version of such zoom Command+
What Web API should I use? Can you suggest documentation on Mozilla developer network or somewhere else.

I have this code for keyboard zoom on Windows:

```
    if (e.ctrlKey && (e.key === '+' || e.key === '=' || e.key === '-')) {
        // '+' can be '=' on some keyboards
        console.log('zoom in action ' + e.key);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

But for mac it would be slightly different. Is there maybe some generic keyboard zoom event instead on detecting particular keys?